# Field validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to iterate over a group of text fields and I want to see if these fields have been enhanced by the user or not. The problem is, even though I have provided the text fields with values, it occurs like I have not provided any value in the text fields. I have provided with JSFIDDLE to have a clear view of what I'm explaining.

### HTML Structure:

```
<div id='manage-appointment'>
<div class="span5">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label>first-name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="first-name" class="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label>last-name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="last-name" class="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label>email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label>Operatorl</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select id='options'>
                                <option value='op1'>Operator1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     <button id='press'>Check empty field</button>
</div>
```

## Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('press').onclick = function() 
{
   var $dialog = $('#manage-appointment');
   $dialog.find('.required').each(function()
    {
           if (!$(this).val() || $(this).has('option').length == 0)
           {
              $(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('error');
              missingRequiredField = true;
           }
    });
}
```

## CSS:

```
.error
{
    background-color:red
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/orhytvwd/6/)

Is anything wrong with the code? When accessing the values from text fields it is taking properly, but enters always in to the error state. Why?

Comment: One problem that I see is that you are not removing any error class for the  control before testing it's validity. The first time through there might be an error thus adding the error class to the control. The next time through, even though the error has been corrected then the error class is not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the `if` statement is true either if the value is false when converted to a boolean, or the element has no `option` children.

As neither of the text boxes has options, all the text boxes will always be included.

To make the condition true only for text boxes that are empty, the condition should be true when the value is empty **and** there are no `option` children:

```
if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).has('option').length == 0)
```

---

As you are using jQuery you should use that to bind the event also.

Instead of checking if each element lacks `option` children, you can simply filter out the `select` elements by using `:not(select)` when getting the elements.

As Kevin Simple showed, you should use the `parent` method to find the immediate parent of the element.

As Jeff pointed out, you should remove the `error` class from the elements, so that the indication is removed when you recheck.

```
$('#press').click(function() {
  var elelments = $('#manage-appointment .required:not(select)');
  elements.parent().removeClass('error');
  elements.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).parent().addClass('error');
      missingRequiredField = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: All are good answers, but I chose you because you said a little 'more. Thank you all, good day.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OR try AND in 
 `if (!$(this).val() && $(this).val().length === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

**JS/ Jquery**

```
$('#press').click(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(index){
        // get Value of text node and trim of leading/ trailing white space 
        var textValue = $(this).val().trim();
        if (textValue.length === 0){
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('error');
            var badcheck = true;
        } else {
             $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('error');
        }
    });
    // stop propegation
    if(badcheck){return false}

});
```

There a few ways to do this. Here is another way. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orhytvwd/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this  for what you want to accomplish

```
document.getElementById('press').onclick = function() 
{
   var $dialog = $('#manage-appointment');
   $dialog.find('.required').each(function()
    {
          if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).has('option').length == 0)
           {
              $(this).parent().addClass('error');
              missingRequiredField = true;
           }
    });
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/letmedoit/oms32rhs/

Comment: The && isn't correct in the condition 'cause in some case the option could be filled and the textbox not